# How to loop through imageButtons correctly?

Tags: java, android, for-loop, imagebutton

Hey guys so I have 3 imageButton icons/tags I want to set. So I do a loop and go through them. Now the user can press a number of tags (such as a food tag, retail tag, housing tag, etc) and that adds to a Global ArrayList. Now if the user only pressed 1 tag and there's three imageButtons that need to be set, I want to set the first imagebutton to the only tag they picked and set the rest to a white blank image, but I keep getting the following error:

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1

here is my loop I dunno what I'm doing wrong here.

```
 private void getIcons()
    {
        iconArray.add(icon1);
        iconArray.add(icon2);
        iconArray.add(icon3);
        for(int i = 0; i < iconArray.size(); i++)
        {
            ImageView button= iconArray.get(i);
            if(Global_Class.getInstance().getValue().tags.size() == 1)
            {
                if(Global_Class.getInstance().getValue().tags.get(i) == null)//Here is where Its giving me an ERROR!!!!!
                {
                    button.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_blank);
                }
                else if(Global_Class.getInstance().getValue().tags.get(i) == "food")
                {
                    button.setImageResource(R.drawable.white_small_icon_food);
                }
                else if(Global_Class.getInstance().getValue().tags.get(i) == "bar")
                {
                    button.setImageResource(R.drawable.white_small_icon_bar);
                }
                else if(Global_Class.getInstance().getValue().tags.get(i) == "club")
                {
                    button.setImageResource(R.drawable.white_small_icon_club1);
                }
                else if(Global_Class.getInstance().getValue().tags.get(i) == "housing")
                {
                    button.setImageResource(R.drawable.white_small_icon_housing);
                }
                else if(Global_Class.getInstance().getValue().tags.get(i) == "sports")
                {
                    button.setImageResource(R.drawable.white_small_icon_sports);
                }
                else if(Global_Class.getInstance().getValue().tags.get(i) == "retail")
                {
                    button.setImageResource(R.drawable.white_small_icon_retail);
                }
                else if(Global_Class.getInstance().getValue().tags.get(i) == "outdoors")
                {
                    button.setImageResource(R.drawable.white_small_icon_outdoors1);
                }
                else if(Global_Class.getInstance().getValue().tags.get(i) == "education")
                {
                    button.setImageResource(R.drawable.white_icon_education);
                }
                else if(Global_Class.getInstance().getValue().tags.get(i) == "landmark")
                {
                    button.setImageResource(R.drawable.white_small_icon_landmark);
                }
            }
            else if(Global_Class.getInstance().getValue().tags.size() == 2)
            {
                if(Global_Class.getInstance().getValue().tags.get(i) == null)
                {
                    button.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_blank);
                }
                else if(Global_Class.getInstance().getValue().tags.get(i) == "food")
                {
                    button.setImageResource(R.drawable.white_small_icon_food);
                }
                else if(Global_Class.getInstance().getValue().tags.get(i) == "bar")
                {
                    button.setImageResource(R.drawable.white_small_icon_bar);
                }
                else if(Global_Class.getInstance().getValue().tags.get(i) == "club")
                {
                    button.setImageResource(R.drawable.white_small_icon_club1);
                }
                else if(Global_Class.getInstance().getValue().tags.get(i) == "housing")
                {
                    button.setImageResource(R.drawable.white_small_icon_housing);
                }
                else if(Global_Class.getInstance().getValue().tags.get(i) == "sports")
                {
                    button.setImageResource(R.drawable.white_small_icon_sports);
                }
                else if(Global_Class.getInstance().getValue().tags.get(i) == "retail")
                {
                    button.setImageResource(R.drawable.white_small_icon_retail);
                }
                else if(Global_Class.getInstance().getValue().tags.get(i) == "outdoors")
                {
                    button.setImageResource(R.drawable.white_small_icon_outdoors1);
                }
                else if(Global_Class.getInstance().getValue().tags.get(i) == "education")
                {
                    button.setImageResource(R.drawable.white_icon_education);
                }
                else if(Global_Class.getInstance().getValue().tags.get(i) == "landmark")
                {
                    button.setImageResource(R.drawable.white_small_icon_landmark);
                }
                else
                {
                    //
                }

            }
            else
            {
                if(Global_Class.getInstance().getValue().tags.get(i) == "food")
                {
                    button.setImageResource(R.drawable.white_small_icon_food);
                }
                else if(Global_Class.getInstance().getValue().tags.get(i) == "bar")
                {
                    button.setImageResource(R.drawable.white_small_icon_bar);
                }
                else if(Global_Class.getInstance().getValue().tags.get(i) == "club")
                {
                    button.setImageResource(R.drawable.white_small_icon_club1);
                }
                else if(Global_Class.getInstance().getValue().tags.get(i) == "housing")
                {
                    button.setImageResource(R.drawable.white_small_icon_housing);
                }
                else if(Global_Class.getInstance().getValue().tags.get(i) == "sports")
                {
                    button.setImageResource(R.drawable.white_small_icon_sports);
                }
                else if(Global_Class.getInstance().getValue().tags.get(i) == "retail")
                {
                    button.setImageResource(R.drawable.white_small_icon_retail);
                }
                else if(Global_Class.getInstance().getValue().tags.get(i) == "outdoors")
                {
                    button.setImageResource(R.drawable.white_small_icon_outdoors1);
                }
                else if(Global_Class.getInstance().getValue().tags.get(i) == "education")
                {
                    button.setImageResource(R.drawable.white_icon_education);
                }
                else if(Global_Class.getInstance().getValue().tags.get(i) == "landmark")
                {
                    button.setImageResource(R.drawable.white_small_icon_landmark);
                }
                else
                {
                    //
                }
            }


        }
    }
```

Here is where i make tags arraylist:

```
public class GlobalVariables
{
    public ArrayList<String> tags = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

And I add to it in another class:

```
 public void onClick(View v)
    {
        switch (v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.imageButton:
                if(food_pressed)
                {
                    ImageButton food_button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
                    food_button.setImageResource(R.drawable.pressed_food);
                    tags.add("food");
                    food_pressed = false;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    ImageButton food_button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
                    food_button.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_food);
                    tags.remove("food");
                    food_pressed = true;
                    break;
                }

        case R.id.imageButton9:
            ImageButton done_button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton9);
            done_button.setImageResource(R.drawable.pressed_done);
            Global_Class.getInstance().getValue().tags = tags;
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),Global_Class.getInstance().getValue().tags.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(toDescription);
            break;

etc...
}
```

Comment: I think only single item is available so try `i-1` instead of `i`

Comment: Show us Global_Class, and tags. Also == is not how you compare Strings in Java. You need to use **.equals("food")** for example. I see alot of repeated code too, which is never a good thing.

Comment: @WalterM I fixed the .equals("food") just forgot to add that in, and i updated the post above.